# Vue don't give @click to a single element when using v-for to create them

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to make every single element created with the v-for the ability to toggle between 'face' class, but it happens that it toggles everything created with the v-for.

```
<div class="deckPairs">
        <div class="deckBoxOne" v-for="base in cards" :key="base.id" >
            <div class="deckBoxBlanc" :class="{face : face}" @click="face = !face">
                <img class="deckPairsImage" style="z-index: 3" alt="Vue logo"  :src="require('../assets/rightCardSide.png')">
            </div>  
            <div class="deckBoxImg" :class="{face : !face}" @click="face = !face">
                <img class="deckPairsImages" style="z-index: 2" :src="require(`../assets/images/${base.url}`)">
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

Script:

```
export default {
    setup() {
        const face = ref(false)
        return { face }
    },

    data(){
        return {
            face: false,

        }
    },

    methods: {
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use a component to encapsulate the functionality.

Comment: That's because you are using the same `face` data for every element inside `v-for`.
Create a component with the `v-for` content and replace it with the new component.

Answer (score 1):

Create a component to encapsulate the `v-for` content.

```
// new-component.vue
<template>
<div>
    <div class="deckBoxBlanc" :class="{face : face}" @click="face = !face">
        <img class="deckPairsImage" style="z-index: 3" alt="Vue logo"  :src="require('../assets/rightCardSide.png')">
    </div>  
    <div class="deckBoxImg" :class="{face : !face}" @click="face = !face">
        <img class="deckPairsImages" style="z-index: 2" :src="require(`../assets/images/${base.url}`)">
    </div>
</div>
</template>

export default {
  data(){
    return {
        face: false
    }
  }
}
```

Now update `v-for` to use the new component.

```
<div class="deckPairs">
    <div class="deckBoxOne" v-for="base in cards" >
        <new-component :key="base.id"/>
    </div>
</div>
```